# how to use U.are.U fingerprint in flutter

Tags: flutter, fingerprint

I'm currently creating a bio data capturing app in flutter. I want to use Digital Persona u.are.u 4500 Fingerprint Reader  to connect it in Android Studio in flutter priject.

My problem is how can I connect the Fingerprint Reader in Android Studio flutter project and how can I use it to register and verify the fingerprint?

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem ?